# Get a list of all registered actions

Tags: plugins, filters, hooks, actions

I'm trying to debug a plugin which I didn't develop and I want to list all the registered actions. I've read this SO thread:

- [WordPress: How do I get all the registered functions for 'the_content' filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5224209/1743124) - StackOverflow

But it's specific to one hook and it's about filters, **not** actions.

Is there any variable like `$wp_filter` or something?

Comment: Use this plugin to show visually on a page [https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-hooks/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-hooks/)

Comment: and you are the developer of that plugin, correct?

Comment: Yes, I made this plugin for myself and then host it in WordPress.

Comment: @Rafiq you should remove your show-hooks link as it is no longer valid.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Filters and actions are both assigned to hooks. Functions assigned to hooks are stored in global `$wp_filter` variable. So all you have to do is to `print_r` it.

```
print_r($GLOBALS['wp_filter']);
```

PS. `add_action` function makes a `add_filter` call. And the latter does `$wp_filter[$tag][$priority][$idx]`.

---

NOTE: you can directly add this code in functions.php, and you will see a debug on your site:

```
add_action('wp', function(){ echo '<pre>';print_r($GLOBALS['wp_filter']); echo '</pre>';exit; } );
```

Comment: nice, but where can i debug them? i tried to add 
if(WP_DEBUG == true){
 global $wp_filter;
 print_r($wp_filter);
} in index.php nad i got NULL

Comment: my bad, shouldn't write global $wp_filter;

Comment: OK, so you worked that out?

Comment: Don't use the wp hook if you get memory problems. Place the code without hook in the functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

Original question related to **action** hooks.

> ...But it's specific to one hook and it's about filters, not actions.
>
> Is there any variable like $wp_filter or something?

So, the answer is Yes, there is. It is `$wp_actions` global variable.

Refer to [**wp-includes/plugin.php**](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/plugin.php) around the line 31 (for WP 6.4.2) it is first declare `$wp_actions` variable to `global` ...without any description.

Scroll down until `function do_action()` line. Read their [doc-block](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/356dd516120dc671bacd9aba60f4bb287855cfb5/wp-includes/plugin.php#L475).

```
* @global int[]     $wp_actions        Stores the number of times each action was triggered.
```

So, this variable is for store the hook type **action** that was triggered.

*For anyone who come to this page from search engine and looking for triggered filters, yes it is in `$wp_filters` NOT `$wp_filter`.*

To see what was triggered actions. In your code, hook to `shutdown` action (or any action that is not too early) and then...

```php
global $wp_actions;
echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($wp_actions, true)).'</pre>';
```