# get_post_meta returns NULL in front-end, but correct result in back-end

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I'm making a custom meta field for posts.

In the back-end, get_post_meta works fine and returns the value.

In the front-end, it returns NULL:

```
$my_custom_field = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_custom_field', true );

var_dump($my_custom_field); // NULL
echo $my_custom_field // ''
```

Things I tried and looked into:

1. my_custom_field gets written to the database with corresponding post_id, and everything seems fine.
2. Using hard-coded post ID gives the same result
3. Putting the call inside the loop gives the same result

**QUESTION:** Why get_post_meta returns NULL, how to fetch the actual value?

**EDIT:** The field is right there in the database:

```
meta_id     post_id     meta_key                        meta_value


139         87          my_custom_field                 IT works!
```

The function arguments reference correct post_id and meta_key which I have checked multiple times, including hard-coding the arguments.

I have also tried to change the name of the meta_key as suggested in some other answer - didn't work.

Backend code is basically this tutorial https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/

**EDIT 2:**

No errors in my logs.

Here is the complete front-end code which returns NULL instead of expected value:

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'output_my_custom_field');
function output_my_custom_field() {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    if ( !empty( $post_id ) ) {
        $my_custom_field = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_custom_field', true );

        var_dump($my_custom_field);
    }   
}
```

**EDIT 3:** Regardless of the hook used (I tried various ones), or even calling a function without any hooks - it still returns NULL.

Comment: Did you a make a var_dump of $post_id too? On the frontend i mean? :)

Comment: Yes, it returns the correct post ID.

Comment: Post your backend code.

Comment: if you pass no key as a parameter: get_post_meta( $post_id, '', true ) it should return you an array of key/values. try to dump this

Comment: @urka_mazurka, did it, but also returns NULL

Comment: Does the meta key `my_custom_field` have a `meta_value` for your posts, in the database?

Comment: @Dan.yes it does.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic: backend code added. But shouldn't get_post_meta return correct result if called with correct parameters, regardless of anything else?

Comment: Does it work for you on a vanilla install (default theme and no plugins) ? Any errors in your logs?

Comment: @birgire just checked and it doesn't. Default theme and no plugins, except the one this code is part of.

Comment: Any errors in your logs? You should consider posting the exact plugin code you use for storing the meta value and the exact loop code you tried to display it, so others can verify it.

Comment: Just checked, no errors in logs. The plugin code is exact same as in the linked tutorial, except for changed field name, and it works for saving the field properly, and retrieving it it properly in the backend. It's the front-end where I use my own code, but it returns NULL (will post it shortly)

Comment: Did you try another place? Specifically not the `the_post` hook.

Comment: @ialocin yes, tried wp_head and wp_footer too, still NULL.

Comment: Are you using any dropins, like an object cache? We certainly had some strange results metadata results using a Redis object cache (our Redis setup was buggy, not the drop-in code). Also, as per @benoti below, try hard-coding $post_id to 87 to confirm if get_the_ID() is working as it should.

Comment: Also, see if you have any filters intercepting the value of the postmeta. the filter is probably **get_post_metadata**, and you can get a full list thusly: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105041/99009

Comment: Are you hooking within another hook?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure I understand the question or problem, but this ought to work, I think:

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'output_my_custom_field');

function output_my_custom_field( $post_object ) {

    $post_id = $post_object->ID;

    // why the conditional (and redundant !empty) ?
    // if ( !empty($post_id) ) ) { 

        $my_custom_field = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_custom_field', true );

        var_dump($my_custom_field);

    // see above
    // }  

 }
```

Comment: Wondering whether this solution has been tried or not.

Answer (score 0):

In a function context, `output_my_custom_field()` can not use template tag like `get_the_ID()`, and it returns null. In a function, external data must be provide via the function parameters `output_my_custom_field($post)` or set with global `global $post` .

When using `the_post` action, you need to add `$post_object` parameter to the function. [See `the_post` example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/the_post)

**`the_post` is only use Iterate the post index in the loop.** If you want to display a custom field value, you can use `the_content` or create a shortcode.

A simple to return the custom .field before the content.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'output_my_custom_field');

function output_my_custom_field($content) {

     global $post; 

    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $post_title = $post->post_title;

    if ( !empty( $post_id ) ) {
        $my_custom_field = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_custom_field', true );

        var_dump($my_custom_field);
    $content = $my_custom_field . $content;
    }   
    return $content;
}
```

If you want to use template tag in your function, your need to add `setup_postdata( $post );` .

```
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'output_my_custom_field');

    function output_my_custom_field($content) {
       global $post;
    setup_postdata($post);

        $post_id = get_the_ID();

        if ( !empty( $post_id ) ) {
             $my_custom_field = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_custom_field', true );

            var_dump($my_custom_field);

            wp_reset_postdata();
        }   
     return $content;
    }
```

In your case there's no need to reset the post data with `wp_reset_postdata()`, because this function restore the original query (and your running on the same one).

Hope it helps to make it work !

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and still getting NULL. I was actually getting the correct post_id, but even when I tried to hard-code it, still the result is same.

Comment: I edit some things, action name.... become add_filter

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but I can't "comment".

Have you checked the posts that you're trying to retrieve this information from?

Are the posts marked as private (admin only) or not published?

Try creating another WordPress account with limited access (but higher rights than a regular user) and see if it works.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's just the hook issue you are using 'the_post', try an other one which suits here, like I just tried using 'init' and its working just fine.

```
add_action( 'init', 'output_my_custom_field');
function output_my_custom_field() {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    if ( !empty( $post_id ) ) {
        $my_custom_field = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_custom_field', true );

        var_dump($my_custom_field);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Tried it, not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$my_custom_field = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_custom_field', false );
var_dump($my_custom_field);
```

It could be that you created the meta field with the wrong version of `add_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_custom_field', 'IT works!', false )`