# Using apply_filters('the_content', $custom_query->post_content) alters output

Tags: wp-query, filters, get-post

Disclaimer: sorry if this has been asked/answered, but I couldn't find the right search phrase to get something similar.

I'm editing a template for a site I did not build, and I stumbled across funky behaviour. It's probably intentional and not a bug, but can someone explain why this happens?

This site uses a plugin called `Teams` that allows the client to input their staff members. It appears to use `single.php` to output the team members (which in turn seems to load content-single.php via `get_template_part( 'content', 'single' );`.

In the footer of the site, a disclaimer was hardcoded like this:

```
$disclaimer_post_id = 311;
$disclaimer_query = get_post($disclaimer_post_id);
$disclaimer = apply_filters('the_content', $disclaimer_query->post_content);
echo $disclaimer;
```

So! On each "regular" page on the site, this works just fine. However, when viewing a single team member, it actually re-outputs their fields (name/title, writeup/description, even social media links and edit button like a normal WP post) so instead of a disclaimer we get duplicated content in the footer from above.

I went through and did a `print_r()` on `$disclaimer_query` and I can see that `$disclaimer_query->post_content` is actually the disclaimer text!

Here's my question:

> Why does `apply_filters()` alter the output? Does it have something to do with the fact that no custom query seems to be used before `get_post()` is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_content` filter takes only one parameter - `$content`, so you can't check what post this `$content` comes from.

So if the plugin Team performs incorrect checks (it can for example use `is_singular( <POST_TYPE> )`), then it will modify all contents printed on single team member page.

You'll have to check what functions are assigned to `the_content` hook and check what exactly are they doing...

Comment: I'm still confused - we're supplying the content from our custom query of `get_post` and I know from debugging that content that it's correct (it's the disclaimer). So what do you mean I can't check what post it comes from? It's only when `apply_filters` is called that it gets changed.

Comment: `apply_filters` calls functions that are assigned to this hook. You have to check what functions are assigned to it and how do they work. Here's the answer showing how to find them: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105039/get-a-list-of-all-registered-actions/105041#105041

Comment: Ohhhh. I think I see what you're saying. I'll check out that other question. Thanks!